# How to reset the number of transactions if new month is come

Tags: java

How can i can reset the transactions number from ONE if new month is come.. for example, last entry is 17020005 become 17030001. The code is working but not reset transaction number from one when new month is come.
 The code which i am using is

```
public void new(){
     Date date =new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMM");
    String time = sdf.format(date); 

try{
    Connection con = new Connection ();
    con.openConnection();
    con.statement = con.dbConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = con.statement.executeQuery("select right(id_sell,4) as id from sell");  

    if (rs.first()==false){
            txtId.setText(time+"0001");  
        }
    else
    {
            rs.last();
            int no = rs.getInt(1)+1;
            String cno = String.valueOf(no);
            int pjg_cno = cno.length();
            for (int i=0;i<4-pjg_cno;i++){
                cno = "0"+cno;
           }
           txtId.setText(time+cno);
        }       

    }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fail!");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting if any?

Comment: Fetch the full id (not just the last 4 digits) then check if the first 4 digits are the same as your `time`.

Comment: The code is working @jack but idk how to reset when new month is coming..

Answer (score 0):

As Henry suggests, it looks like your "id_sell" values are made up of the year, month and a unique integer - if so, you could change your SQL query to include a WHERE clause to match the first four digits of your time string - `WHERE id_sell LIKE '1703%'`.

However, long term (and assuming you control the DB structure), I'd suggest thinking about storing those values separately - if you had a `month` field and a `transaction_id` field it would be much easier and more efficient to query this data.

I'd also suggest thinking about whether you could generate IDs on the database using a sequence - it's hard for this java code to guarantee uniqueness and raises potential concurrency issues.